# 400 Bad request Error in mapping nested json objects to java.util.Map in spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to spring.

I am facing problem in mapping json object from angular to Map in spring controller. The definition of my controller is as follows :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/PnPanel.go/FlowSheets/data/*", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST},
                        consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Map invokeFlowsheets
(
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    @RequestBody Map<String, Map> req
)
```

My Request body looks like

```
{"reqParams":"{\"name\":\"sachin\"}","appParams":"{\"name\":\"sachin1\"}","otherInfo":"{\"name\":\"sachin2\"}"}
```

As you can see, I am sending nested json objects and I want to map them into java.util.Map, But I am getting 400 error from spring telling that request was syntactically bad.

Sorry for bad english and for such a silly question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: clearly you are using something to perform the JSON mapping; perhaps jackson.  Write a test class that uses your JSON mapping library directly.  This should help you debug your problem.  Also, consider generating example JSON with the JSON mapping library.  The JSON you included does not match a map<String, Map>.  it is an object with three string parameters (that happen to contain json in the string values).

Comment: first of all change your req object as Map<String,Object>. 400 means you are not sending a required parameter. Could you please share how do you send this request to the spring controller ?

Comment: Please post the clientside code that sends the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your JSON string into :

```
{"reqParams":{"name":"sachin"},"appParams":{"name":"sachin1"},"otherInfo":{"name":"sachin23"}}
```

Notice that `{}` are not surrounded with `""`.